# Realm on Oracle Linux

Tags: linux, oracle-linux

I am trying to integrate a Linux server with an Active Directory. I am using https://fedorahosted.org/sssd/wiki/Configuring_sssd_with_ad_server#JoiningtheLinuxclienttotheADdomainmanually

The article says to run a realm discover command, but I am unable to install realmd on my server. I tried yum install realmd, but it did not work. Does realm just not work for Oracle?

I am running Oracle Linux 5.11

Answer (score 0):

There's no Oracle Linux 5.11. The latest Oracle Linux Release is 7.5.

And realmd is available, see http://public-yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/latest/x86_64/index.html

Comment: According to [Oracle Linux | Release History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Linux) 5.11 is a released version. It was released 2014-09-23.